# Como remover linhas em branco múltiplas em sequência com vim?

Tags: vim

Estou com o seguinte problema, tenho um arquivo com código todo bagunçado, muitas linhas em branco. Eu tentei remover as linhas em branco de acordo com o post [post sobre deleção de linha](https://portalfisica.com/2017/06/10/apagando-linhas-em-branco-no-vim/), mas ele removeu todas as linhas em branco.  Eu queria deixar pelo menos uma linha em branco entre cada linha do código.

Comment: Experimentei um jeito agora, mas certamente tem um jeito mais fácil de fazer. Eu consegui primeiro removendo todas as linhas em branco `:g/^$/:delete` depois posicionei no início do arquivo `gg` e gravei uma macro com o conteúdo: `qsA<CR>j<Esc>q` depois de salvo a macro, vi que o arquivo ficou com, por exemplo 520 linhas, então apliquei a macro 520 vezes via comando `520@s`. O problema dessa abordagem é que devo saber o numero de linhas após remover as em branco, ou seja, **não é eficaz**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Desculpe pelo meu pobre português. Eu usei o Google Tradutor. Edite qualquer gramática ruim que você veja :)*

---

Você pode usar o seguinte comando:

```
:%s/^$\n^$
```

Isso informa ao vim para remover qualquer ocorrência de duas linhas vazias próximas uma da outra. Normalmente, você gostaria de usar

```
:%s/^$\n^$//g
```

Para terminar o comando, mas não precisamos da opção **`/g`** porque só pode haver uma correspondência por linha, e não precisamos das barras diagonais, uma vez que o vim não requer isso.

Answer (score 1):

Eu criei duas funções no meu ~/.vimrc 
A primeira tem como objetivo executar comandos sem alterar a posição do 
cursor e os registros de busca, pois quando localizamos linhas em branco consecutivas com o objetivo de apaga-las esse registro fica armazenado, ou seja, a função Preserve pode ser usada em outras situações.

A segunda é a função que de fato vai deletar as  linhas em branco.

```
if !exists('*Preserve')
    function! Preserve(command)
        " Preparation: save last search, and cursor position.
        let save_cursor = getpos(".")
        let old_query = getreg('/')
        execute a:command
        " Clean up: restore previous search history, and cursor position
        call setpos('.', save_cursor)
        call setreg('/', old_query)
    endfunction
endif


" remove consecutive blank lines
" see Preserve function definition
fun! DelBlankLines()
    keepjumps call Preserve("g/^\\n\\{2,}/d")
endfun
command! -nargs=0 DelBlank :call DelBlankLines()
```

Se desejar pode até mapear para `<leader>d` dessa forma:

```
:nnoremap <leader>d :call DelBlankLines()
```

OBS: `<leader>` por padrão é barra invertida mas em muitos sistemas é configurado para "Vírgula" `,`.

Answer (score 1):

Substituir 2 ou mais linhas em branco (`\n\n\n*`) por
duas linhas em branco (`\r\r`)

```
:%s/\n\n\n*/\r\r/
```

Nota: em vim, nas substituições usa-se `\r` em vez de `\n`

Answer (score 0):

```
:g/^$/:delete
```

ou

```
:g/^$/d
```

- g = global, documento inteiro
- ^ = início de linha
- $ = final de linha
  Obs.: o padrão ^$ significa tudo que não tem nada entre o início e
  final de linha
- d | delete = apagar a linha que casa com o padrão acima